# Passing a value from jquery to php using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my problem is following:

I am using this code to pass a value to a different file called "benutzerstart.php". Debugging through the jquery shows, that the value in "var beta" is correct.

I do get a problem with getting the value to a PHP variable.

The error code is : "Notice: Undefined index: param in C:\xampp\htdocs\KVP\benutzerstart.php on line 76"

Referring to the error code my suggestion is that the passed value is not really passed to the php file.

JQuery code:

```
<script>
          $('#form').submit(function() {
            var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($Email) ?>;          
            var newMail = $.trim($('#Email').val())     
            var pw1 = $.trim($('#Password').val()) 
            var mailVorhanden = false;
            var pwRichtig = false;
            var idVondemShit = -1;
            var tempindex = -1;

            for ( var i = 0; i < arrayFromPHP.length; i++ ) {
         //   $.each(arrayFromPHP, function (i, val) {
            if(newMail === arrayFromPHP[i].Email ){
              mailVorhanden = true;
              tempindex = i;
              break;
           } 
          };
              if (mailVorhanden === true)
              {
               if(pw1 === arrayFromPHP[tempindex].pw) 
               {
                idVondemShit = arrayFromPHP[tempindex].idName;
                pwRichtig = true;
                 if(arrayFromPHP[tempindex].mode === "1")
               {  
                location.href='startseite.html';
                pwRichtig = false;
               }  
               }
               else
               {
                alert('Passwort oder Nutzername falsch.');
               }
              }
              else{
               alert('Passwort oder Nutzername falsch.');
              }
              var beta = arrayFromPHP[tempindex].idName
              $.ajax({
                url: 'benutzerstart.php',
                data: {'param' : 'beta'},
              });
              return pwRichtig  
        });    
        </script>
```

PHP code from "benutzerstart.php":

```
<?php
  // Collect data
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "Floradix94");
  mysql_select_db("hallo");
  $tstID =  $_GET['param'];
  $sql= "SELECT         erfassung.Verbesserungsvorschlag,erfassung.megusta,login.Email,erfassung.id,erfassung.Betre    ff FROM (erfassung INNER JOIN login ON erfassung.loginid=login.loginid)"; 
  $query=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $modals[] = array(
  'id' => 'modal' . $row['id'],
  'href' => '#modal' . $row['id'],
  'FormDoneId' => $row['id'] . 'FormDoneId',
  'Email' =>$row['Email'],
  'Verbesserungsvorschlag' => $row['Verbesserungsvorschlag'],
  'megusta' => $row['megusta'],
  'betreff' => $row['Betreff'],
);

 }
  ?>
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
data: {'param' : 'beta'},
```

To

```
data: {param : 'beta'},
```

Comment: Hello Olvier, I should've said that I've tested different possibilities before, including yours. Just tried it again and I recieve the same error.

Comment: Can you check in a developer console the request sent ? You can access it with F12 shortcut on all browsers. For Chrome, watch in the Network tab : click on the request, and look at parameters in "Headers" tab to be sure param is well given. Check also that the request use GET method.

Comment: Also, PHP Side, you can use `var_dump` to check `$_GET` array. You can  use `$_REQUEST` array to get the param value with both GET and POST methods.

Comment: Hey, I have checked the Network tab and this is what I get. http://imgur.com/r3frLmo "Anfrage" means "Request" in English.

Comment: Why is there two request here ? The first is OK : uses GET and send param parameter. The second is POST and there's nothing in it.

Comment: I've tried the var_dumb and $Request. What I get is an array with the password and the username. But I actually try to 'POST' the id of the user in the php file and not the mail or password. http://imgur.com/f67lppa

Comment: When you handle submit event on a form, you have to `return false` at the end to prevent the form from being submitted. Here, I see you `return pwRichtig` ( btw you forgot a ; ) : are you sure this is always false ? If it returns true, then your ajax request to benutzerstart.php is canceled at the moment form is submitted.